# How can apply multithreading to speed up the beautiful soup to scrape data fast

Tags: python, json, multithreading, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am not familiar with multithreading and how I can apply it to scrape the data fast because beautifulsoup scrape the data slow can tell how I  apply multithreading to my code this is the page link https://baroul-timis.ro/tabloul-avocatilor/

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd



url = "https://baroul-timis.ro/get-av-data?param=toti-avocatii"

base_url= 'https://baroul-timis.ro'

headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}

productlink=[]
data = requests.get(url).json()
for i, d in enumerate(data["data"], 1):
    link = BeautifulSoup(d["actions"], "html.parser").a["href"]
    comp=base_url+link
    productlink.append(comp)
test=[]   
for link in productlink:
    wev={}
    r =requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    prod=soup.find_all('div',class_='user-info text-left mb-50')
    for pip in prod:
        title=pip.find('h4').text
        wev['title']=title
        
        
        try:
            phone=pip.select('span',class_='font-weight-bolder')[2].text
           
        except:
            pass
        wev['phone']=phone.split('\xa0')
        
        
        
        
        
        
        try:
            email=pip.select('span',class_='font-weight-bolder')[3].text
        except:
            pass
        wev['email']=email.split('\xa0')
        
        
        
        test.append(wev)
        
        
        
df = pd.DataFrame(test)
print(df)
```

Comment: If you have many urls then multi-threading will speed up downloading. But processing will not improve. This is because python threads work well with IO but not on CPU bound tasks.

Comment: I have 968 URL how can I apply threading on URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multithreading is ideal for this kind of thing because there will be lots of I/O waits while the URLs are accessed and their data acquired. Here's how you could re-work it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

url = "https://baroul-timis.ro/get-av-data?param=toti-avocatii"
base_url= 'https://baroul-timis.ro'

headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}

test = []

def process(link):
    wev={}
    r =requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    prod=soup.find_all('div',class_='user-info text-left mb-50')
    for pip in prod:
        title=pip.find('h4').text
        wev['title']=title
        try:
            wev['phone']=pip.select('span',class_='font-weight-bolder')[2].text.split('\xa0')
        except:
            pass
        try:
            wev['email']=pip.select('span',class_='font-weight-bolder')[3].text.split('\xa0')
        except:
            pass
        test.append(wev)

productlink=[]
data = requests.get(url).json()
for d in data["data"]:
    link = BeautifulSoup(d["actions"], "lxml").a["href"]
    productlink.append(base_url+link)

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(process, productlink)

df = pd.DataFrame(test)
print(df)
```

This generates a 941 row dataframe in <44 seconds on my system (24 threads) - i.e., ~20 URLs/second

Note: If you don't already have lxml installed, you'll need it. It's generally faster than html.parser

**EDIT:**

Multiprocessing version

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

url = "https://baroul-timis.ro/get-av-data?param=toti-avocatii"
base_url = 'https://baroul-timis.ro'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}


def process(link):
    wev = {}
    test = []
    r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    prod = soup.find_all('div', class_='user-info text-left mb-50')
    for pip in prod:
        wev['title'] = pip.find('h4').text
        try:
            wev['phone'] = pip.select('span', class_='font-weight-bolder')[2].text.split('\xa0')
        except:
            pass
        try:
            wev['email'] = pip.select('span', class_='font-weight-bolder')[3].text.split('\x0a')
        except:
            pass
        test.append(wev)
    return test


def main():
    productlink = []
    for d in requests.get(url).json()["data"]:
        link = BeautifulSoup(d["actions"], "lxml").a["href"]
        productlink.append(base_url+link)
    test = []
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for r in executor.map(process, productlink):
            test.extend(r)

    df = pd.DataFrame(test)
    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: can it provide you output

Comment: @AmenAziz What do you mean? This provides the same output as your code - i.e., a dataframe

Comment: I mean  you can  change  your  code   as  @Shiplu Mokaddim mentioned in his code  I read documentation` of ProcessPoolExecutor.` they will be   fast but I do not how can I can implement it to my code

Comment: @AmenAziz With your data and on my machine, multithreading is slightly faster than multiprocessing. Did you try running the code in this answer?

Comment: your code is working but it 5 minute to scrape data

Comment: @AmenAziz It takes less than 1 minute on my machine. You either have a low capacity computer or slow internet speed. How many CPUs do you have?

Comment: I have icore 7 generation  but the space in my C drive` is finish

Comment: but Why do they show me 940 entries there is 948 entries in website can you provide me solution for these

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245658/discussion-between-albert-winestein-and-amen-aziz).

Comment: The last entry in the dataframe is number 940 but the first is number 0. So you have 941 entries. You have 948 URLs but 7 of them fail. Therefore your dataframe contents are completely correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ThreadPoolExecutor` if you want to use threading.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

links = [...] # All you product urls goes here.
def do_work(link):
   ...
   # Write code to process 1 url here. 
# Run 10 threads at a time
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(8)
results = executor.map(do_work, links)
```

I **recommend to use `ProcessPoolExecutor`**. This not only works with IO but also with CPU bound tasks. It'll also use all your CPUs.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

links = [...] # All you product urls goes here.
def do_work(link):
   ...
   # Write code to process 1 url here. 
# Run 8 processes parallel.
executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(8)
results = executor.map(do_work, links, chunksize=40)
```

Here the results will be the list of return values from the `do_work` function. It's better not to return a huge data. Then serializing that data will make the process very slow. Instead save it to db or file.

Read more about the [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

Comment: Just for the sake of interest... I modified my answer to use multiprocessing (20 workers being the default on my machine) and it was slightly slower than multithreading with the default 24 threads. Almost certainly due to data serialisation

Comment: can you change your  code like these `Shiplu Mokaddim ` has said because I can not understand how can I apply it to my code the brother has said

Comment: @Shiplu Mokaddim  I have  my answer but it has `column and index are empty`

Comment: @AmenAziz That's an issue in the Pandas. Probably some of the url doesn't have correct format or missing data.